# how can i avoid duplicate field in jackson in serialisation

Tags: spring

I'm using Jackson to serialise My Rest Api

POJO :

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeInfo(include= JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT,use= JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
public class Project implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String projectName;
    private String resource;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Collaborator> collaborators;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Task> tasks;
    public Project(String projectName, String resource) {
        this.projectName = projectName;
        this.resource = resource;
    }
}
```

output:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "dateDebut": "2022-05-31T13:14:39.091+00:00",
  "dateFin": "2022-05-31T13:14:39.091+00:00",
  "project": {
    "Project": {
      "id": 2,
      "projectName": "project Suivi Activite 2",
      "resource": "resource 2",
      "collaborators": []
    }
  },
  "collaborator": null,
  "days": []
}
```

how can i avoid field "Project" inside "project" ?
@JsonTypeInfo(include= JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT,use= JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME) ?

Comment: It shouldn't be there, so you are probably wrapping this inside something else... Do you construct a DTO somewhere, if so don't use the project but copy the fields.

Comment: i didnt use DTO

Comment: You did use something as what is being send as JSON isn't a representation of this entity.

Comment: Thanks i used ProjectDTO and associed with @JsonSerializer